# Local array is changing global array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array with 8 other arrays inside, and also a function to join everything together and return it, but for some reason the function also affects the global one, although I have not told it to. I want map to bw able to used in functions but i dont want this to happen if I dont explicitly use map in the function.:

```
def joinArray(array)
    for i in 0..(array.length() - 1) do
        array[i] = array[i].join()
    end
    return array
end

$map = Array.new(8){Array.new(8)}
for i in 0..7 do
    for x in 0..7 do
        $map[i][x] = $square
    end
end

#before running this $map would be [["0", "0", "0", etc], ["0", "0", etc], etc]
puts (joinArray($map)).join("\n")
#but after running $map looks like this ["00000000","00000000", etc]

Edit: Unlike other languages ruby doesn’t create another variable when a variable is passed through as a parameter. The way i fixed this was by passing $map.dup instead of $map.
```

Comment: "although I have not told it to" - you also didn't tell it not to [affect the global array]. What you pass as an argument to `joinArray` is a reference to your global array, not a copy.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev so what is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of mutating input array, I'd create a copy (using `map`, for example)

Comment: Hint: how many arrays have you created in your code?